# Feature Layer is getting null bounds with featurecollection derived from RasterToVectorProcess

Tags: java, geotiff

Null Pinter Exception simply means that it is because of value is getting null. But In case of using APis such as GeoTiff it becomes annoying to find out the error in usage.

My code is as follows:

```
System.out.println("vectorization starts");

GridCoverage2D srcCoverage = new GeoTiffReader(new File("E:/output/ll_processed.TIFF")).read(new GeneralParameterValue[]{policy, gridsize, useJaiRead});

SimpleFeatureCollection fc = RasterToVectorProcess.process(srcCoverage, 3, cov.getEnvelope(), Collections.singletonList(0.0d), true, null);

System.out.println("process ends");
System.out.println("vectorization ends");
//MapContext map = new DefaultMapContext();
//map.setTitle("raster to vector conversion");
Style style = SLD.createPolygonStyle(Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, 1.0f);
//map.addLayer(fc, style);
//map.getLayerBounds();
//JMapFrame.showMap(map);

MapContent mapContent= new MapContent();
mapContent.setTitle("Illegal Mining");
Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(fc, style,"VectorLayer");

//int boundary = 10;
// ReferencedEnvelope env2 = new  ReferencedEnvelope(srcCoverage.getEnvelope().getMinimum(0) - boundary, srcCoverage.getEnvelope().getMaximum(0) + boundary,
    //srcCoverage.getEnvelope().getMinimum(1) - boundary, srcCoverage.getEnvelope().getMaximum(1) + boundary, srcCoverage.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());

//mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(fc.getBounds());
Line 199 : if(layer.getBounds()!=null) // here the error is coming also tried with if(layer != null && layer.getBounds()!=null) 
 {
    mapContent.addLayer(layer);
}else{
    System.out.println("Layer bounds are null");
}
mapContent.getViewport().setCoordinateReferenceSystem(
        DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
```

Error

> at org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer.getBounds(FeatureLayer.java:199)

I am trying to convert Tiff to Vector image and Then I want to store it on disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: change if(layer.getBounds()!=null) to if(layer != null && layer.getBounds()!=null)

Comment: No this is not orthodox, this is usage of GeoTIFF Api. As in my code I used Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(fc, style,"VectorLayer"); which should initialize it.

Comment: Actually problem is with getBounds is null and I have no setter from API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your `featureSource` is null, since the [geotools `FeatureLayer` class](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/map/FeatureLayer.java) method `getBounds()` uses the `featureSource` to retrieve the bounds, but in the constructor `FeatureLayer` doesn't check whether the `featureSource` is `null`.

The `featureSource` is the first argument to the constructor of `FeatureLayer`. In your case, that's variable `SimpleFeatureCollection fc`.

Most likely, the method `process.process` returned `null` so `fc` is null.

Minor Change in RasterToVectorProcess.java

```
       //features.add(builder.buildFeature(null));
                //System.out.println("ignored");
                //add
                System.out.println("adding...");
                SimpleFeature feature = builder.buildFeature(null);
                ((Collection<SimpleFeature>) features).add(feature);
```

Comment: fc is derived from RasterToVectorProcess.process , i am troubleshooting it.

Comment: Although fc.getBounds() is working, there is something defective with features.